# Exception in accessing inner dictionary in Swift

Tags: swift

Code:

```
{
    "methodName": "LOGIN",
    "errorCode": -1,
    "responseMsg": "Login success",
    "response": {
        "userId": 28871,
        "firstName": "Test",
        "lastName": "Dentist",
        "contactId": 28720
    }
}
```

This is what i get as response from NSURL Connection.

```
if response != ""{
            var resMsg: String = dataDic["responseMsg"] as String

            if resMsg == "Login success"{
                var resDic: NSDictionary = dataDic["response"] as NSDictionary
                var userId: String = resDic["userId"] as String
            } 
        }
```

When i try access userId it gives exception as Exc_Break point exception.It is working fine in Objective C.How do i modify code to access inner dictionary.any help will be appreciated.thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that `resDic` is not `nil`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try

```
var userId: NSNumber = resDic["userId"] as NSNumber
```

As you can see in `dataDic` the value for key `userID` is a number. Since `dataDic` can contain either a string, number and a dictionary, its type is most likely inferred as  [String:NSObject]. As a result you should cast `userId` as `NSNumber`, instead of swift native type `string`